# function parameter names starting with underscore

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Is there any difference between parameters starting with underscore and normal parameters in python ?

eg:

```
def fun1(_data, _val):
    ....
    ....

def fun2(data, val):
    ....
    ....
```

Why I asked this question is because, in pycharm I could see the parameter data as blurred (It wasn't using anywhere) and the parameter _data as non-blurred (which was also not using anywhere in the function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in practice, and for function parameters you wouldn't really do this.

In python, there is a convention that a single underscore means the var/method is private, so `_data` should not be used by 3rd party apps. You'd often use this for e.g variables only available within a class.

Double underscore vars, e.g. `__data` is just an extra level of "don't use this from outside the class".

Usually, you'd use these to indicate to other devs that they shouldn't access eg. `classname._var`, but you would instead provide some kind of getter or setter method instead.

Comment: So when you use this in a class it will be considered as a protected member, right?

Comment: Only by convention. It's not enforced by the language.